# Can't set default proofing language in MS Word 2010

Tags: windows, microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2010

I have English and Croatian proofing tools installed, and my Windows 7 (in English language) has Croatian regional settings. I can't set up default proofing to English.

I can, in review tab switch between proofing tools and re-check document, but every time I create new document proofing is set up to Croatian.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this, I have to change the input language before starting Word using <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd>.

Comment: Proofing Language is selected from input language, here is a post with more explanation https://superuser.com/a/1442448/156235