# Outlook 2016 language detection doesn't work

Tags: microsoft-outlook, language, office365, microsoft-outlook-2016, proofing

I'm baffled, as the title says, the auto detection just doesn't work. I can manually change the language of any given email, but it won't autodetect. The languages are pretty different, so it shouldn't be that hard...

Anyone had any similar problem?

Pretty irritating, as I use the languages 50-50...

Though below image has 2 languages in one document, the detection doesn't work on single language emails either. Full Hungarian or full English - still no successful detection.

Whatever I set as default is used from then on in all documents, regardless of the language of the current document.

[image: Autodetect doesn't work]

Comment: Have you tried with more that one statement/longer text?
Sometime it can require more words (also time) to tune on the language, where it is set to autodetect

Comment: That's curious. If I copy-paste a long Hungarian text, the second part of it is immediately recognized. The first stays "English". If I copy-paste it in bits, it is not recognized (even after 5 minutes). This just made everything more confusing. Wow. Maybe I'll do a bug report.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Edit: *Scroll down for solution.*

I can confirm that the Microsoft Outlook's feature "Detect language **automatically**" works only under special circumstances. *Once* per e-mail.
There are 3 preconditions:

1. Set the *default* language to other than English (**Review** > **Language** -> **Set Proofing Language...**> [Select language] > **Set As Default**)
2. Start writing in language *that is not English* with correspondingly selected keyboard layout
3. Switch the keyboard layout (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> or <kbd>Win key</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> in Windows) before writing in English.

The following image shows and explains the steps performed.
[Outlook proofing language test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvYIW.png)

So basically, you can write in one language and then switch to English once. If you want to write again in the previous language you can copy-paste the text or just one character from before or use the menu to set proofing language.

By the way, the signature has automatically "Do not check spelling or grammar" property set so if you select and delete it, the proofing for following text won't be enabled unless you set it manually.

## Workaround

Other than with the conditions mentioned above, the fastest and most reliable option for multiple language proofing in one e-mail (so far) is by setting the language manually. To have the button easily accessible:

1. Right-click on the Ribbon bar > **Customize the Ribbon...** (Or go to Outlook options: **File** > **Options** > **Customize Ribbon**)
2. On the right pane press **New Group** (Optionally rename it to e.g. "*Language*")
3. On the left pane select in Choose commands from: "**All commands**"
4. Scroll to and select "**Set Proofing Language**" command and press "**Add**" button or drag and drop it in the newly created group.

[Outlook options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjTWp.png)

Press "**OK**" and you will have the "Set Proofing Language" easily accessible from the Ribbon bar so that each time *before* you need to write in different language (other than default) you can select the proofing language with 3 clicks.

### Solution

Apparently it boils down to the Windows Language settings: If you have just one language installed (e.g. English) with multiple language keyboard layouts in Windows Settings, the proofing tools won't recognize the text correctly automatically.

To let proofing tools recognize the text in each language you need to have the language installed, not just the keyboard layout. To do that (on *Windows 10*) go to **Windows Settings** (<kbd>Win key</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd>) > **Time & Language** > **Language** > **Add a language** > [select your language] > **Next**

From the Install language features window just the "**Basic typing**" option is sufficient. Press **Install**.

[image: Windows Language settings]

To test open a **New Email** window in Outlook (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>) and start typing in your selected language. Now switch to different language by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> or using the language selection menu near the clock in the Windows taskbar:

[image: Language selection menu]

The proofing tools should work *automatically*:

[image: Proofing tools working correctly in Outlook for Office 365]

Note that each *pair* of words is written in different selected language and automatically (without touching the mouse) recognized by proofing tools. 
(1st line: English, Latvian, German
2nd line: German, English, Latvian)

**Note** - two things to bear in mind:

1. *If* you have enabled default *Signature* for new e-mails in Outlook options (**File** > **Options** > **Mail** > **Signature...**) or add the signature manually (through **Insert** > **Signature**) before writing any text *and* start writing a new e-mail in a language *other* than the default in your Outlook settings, it won't be recognized correctly regardless of the currently selected language in your Windows language menu. To work around that just simply cycle through (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>) your languages one time.
2. There is a small delay after selecting different language for the first time. If you start typing immediately after switching language the proofing tools might treat the text as in previously selected language. 
   To avoid that just wait a second before starting to write in a new language for the first time.

Comment: Looks like I finally have found a solution - I have updated my answer.

Comment: You deserve far more reputation than I can give you!

Comment: Even if this does work, it's far from optimal and feels very much like a workaround of an issue that should be solved by Microsoft. In my opinion the keyboard layout should not be bound to the language I am writing in.

Comment: I agree that it is confusing and inconvenient - the spellcheck could just get by looking up a word in every dictionary and it would work fine apart from some edge-cases where a user misspells a word which actually exists in another language.

Answer (score -1):

This because the spell checker and syntax highlight can work for only one language per document (doc, email, whatever office file).
You cannot mix two languages in the same email/doc and have the checker to follow your mixture

Comment: Sorry, the picture was a bad example then. It doesn't even detect full Hungarian / full English emails either. I'll update my question.

Comment: This is NOT correct, as @kristoz mentioned and presented in a print screen - the same document can have text corrected in multiple languages, if added correctly.