# Office 365 always resets the proofing language

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-outlook, office365

I am subscriber for Office 365, my Windows is set up in 'en-US' but my native language is German. So I installed Office in 'de-DE' as well.

Now everytime I want to write an e-mail or Word document in German, it says that's everything is wrong. So I mark everything and change the proofing language to German (yes I unchecked the automatic detection). I type a single character and it switches back to "English". I even tried setting it as default language. Actually when I choose "German (Germany)" and type anything it switches to "English (Germany)". Even if I delete something, it never turns back. Like it's truly temporary.

Whatever I do, Word just doesn't stick with another language. I honestly ask myself for what I am paying so much if this feature from Office 97 is not even working...

Any clue what causes this weird behavior? I'm completely out of ideas.

EDIT: As by request I have the following settings:

- Display Language: German (de-DE)
- Installed Languages: German (de-DE), English (en-US)
- Settings: Primary Proofing Language is German, I even removed English from the list

Comment: How did you try switching the proofing language? Does this issue happen within non-Office editors, such as Notepad? Have you tried reinstalling the language pack?

Comment: @SteveFan No of course not. It's an office related issue, but occurs through Outlook and Word. No, not yet. I never installed on anyway. But I will try this when I'm home from work. Ramhound I added the information I know out of my head, if you require any more info I'll update it later.

Comment: Having a different language for your system is problematic. See https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-msoversion_other/proofing-language-keeps-changing-solutions-how-can/c6483d0c-6fe3-41bf-8464-25535d3ec15b?tm=1579788821357.

Answer (score 5):

Please make sure that you have the languages installed *not only* in the Office, but also in **Windows Settings** (<kbd>Win key</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd>) > **Time & Language** > **Language**.

*After* opening a new e-mail window, place the cursor in the text field and make sure to select the correct typing language by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> or using the language selection menu near the clock in the Windows taskbar.  Or by pressing **Review** > **Language** > **Set Proofing Language...** (*without* selecting any text). Then start typing and it should work.

I have explained the issue and solution in greater detail here:
https://superuser.com/a/1442448/212626

Comment: I have tried this for https://superuser.com/q/1604698/72397, unfortunately did not work. The curly check lines come back. Thanks neverthless!

Comment: For me https://superuser.com/a/1604771/72397 number 3 (auto language off) did the trick. Just to share it here as well.

Comment: I had the same issue in Word, and for me the step that solved it was the one that isn't bold in the answer: The proofing language for each new text seems to default to the language selected in the Windows task bar! Setting the language in Word with an empty selection was what I remembered from earlier but that didn't work.